# Recycling light using photovoltaic cell

Tags: solar-cell

Can you recycle light emitted via mobile using photovoltaic cell and feed it to the mobile.?

Comment: Yes. But you cannot create a perpetual cellphone. Thermodynamics dislikes such devices.

Comment: Thanks! Not thinking of perpetual just recycling ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that due to various inefficiencies (and the relatively low light output of a cellphone), this really isn't going to do anything. But go ahead and try to implement it, see what happens.

Comment: Wow, what a concept! So you could drive around all day in your Electric Vehicle, and when you got home at night all you'd have to do to recharge the battery would be to plug into a couple of PVs  and shine the headlights on them until morning... ;)

Comment: Not something like that EM, just harvest all that available light if possible

Comment: Yes, you can recycle light from your cell phone screen; as a joke.  A hand-cranked generator for the cell phone would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3):

There's not much point in it.

You will always lose most of the energy emitted in the light.

LEDs convert maybe 10% of the electrical energy driving them to light.  So, you lose 9 times more energy than you emit.

PV cells are at best 20% efficient, so you've lost 80% of the energy in the emitted light.

The converters needed to change the voltage from the PV cell to the voltage needed to charge the phone are maybe 90% efficient.

Take it all together, and it is a losing proposition.  You would lose more than 90% of the energy it took to create the light in the first place.

Rather than "recycling" light, just turn the backlight or screen off when the phone isn't being used.  You'll save more energy that way, and it will be much easier than trying to recycle emitted light.

---

You do realize that a PV cell in a position to capture all the emitted light would also completely block all view of the phone screen?

Comment: I saw a transparent cell on development so i won't mind the last line. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @jmazaredo:  If the PV cell was transparent then it most certainly couldn't be efficient.  All of the light you can see through the cell is light that it didn't catch and convert to electricity.